# tikz, conditional setting of shape parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, parameters

In my illustration I use simplified sketches of stopwatches (timers), which appear in three different "modes": (1) start of interval (coloured green), (2) time in progress (yellow), and time is expired (red).

[image]

For each of these cases, I determined separate styles which differ from each other only in two lines, see MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
     node distance = 5mm,
       start chain = going right,
boxG/.style 2 args = {name=n#1,
                      shape=rectangle, draw=#2, thick, inner sep=0mm, on chain,
                      node contents={\tikz{
    \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#2!30] (0,0) circle;
    \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
    \draw                       ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
    \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ ( 90:4.0mm);
                                            }}
                      },
boxY/.style 2 args = {name=n#1,
                      shape=rectangle, draw=#2, thick, inner sep=0mm, on chain,
                      node contents={\tikz{
    \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#2!30] (0,0) circle;
    \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
    \draw                       ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
    \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,+1mm) -- ++ (225:4.0mm);
                                            }}
                      },
boxR/.style 2 args = {name=n#1,
                      shape=circle, draw=#2, thick, inner sep=0mm, on chain,
                      node contents={\tikz{
    \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#2!30] (0,0) circle;
    \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
    \draw                       ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
    \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.0mm);
                                            }}
                      },
}
\node[boxG={1}{green}];
\node[boxY={2}{yellow}];
\node[boxR={3}{red}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to determine just one style, where the last two lines are selected regarding the used color, something like this:

```
timer/.style 2 args = {name=n#1,
                      shape=circle, draw=#2, thick, inner sep=0mm, on chain,
                      node contents={\tikz{
    \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#2!30] (0,0) circle;
    \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
    \draw                       ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
%%%% pseudocode for conditional selecting of appropriate last two lines
if #2 = green
    \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ ( 90:4.0mm);
else if #2 = yellow
    \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,+1mm) -- ++ (225:4.0mm);
else if #2 = red
    \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
    \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.0mm);
fi fi fi
%%%%
                        }}}
```

Additional question: in the third timer, why isn't the distance between the inner picture and outer node equal to zero as it is in the first two (finally I would like to have a circle for outer node)?

Comment: Still don't know why, but `inner sep=-1mm` in `boxR` solves last question.

Comment: A simple hack is to use `\@namedef{clock-green}{LAST TWO LINES}` etc for each color (once, in the preamble) and then in the node contents do `\@nameuse{clock-#2}`

Comment: BTW the use of nested tikz pictures is discouraged, if you are using PGF3 you can use the great new `pic` action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another suggestion using a node inside the `pic`. You can refer to this node and its anchors by `<picname>-c` outside the `pic` code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand*\clcol{}

\tikzset{
    pics/clock/.style={code={
    \edef\clcol{#1}
    \node(-c)[draw=\clcol,thick,minimum size=7mm+\pgflinewidth]{};
    \coordinate(q)at(-c.center);
    \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=\clcol!30](q)circle;
    \fill[radius=3.5mm-.5*\pgflinewidth,white] (q) -- + (90:{3.5mm-.5*\pgflinewidth}) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (q) + (\i:2.5mm) -- +(\i:3mm);
    \ifdefstring{\clcol}{green}{%
      \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (q)++(+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
      \draw[thick,->]             (q)++( 0mm,-1mm) -- +( 90:4.0mm);}{}
    \ifdefstring{\clcol}{yellow}{%
      \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (q)++(+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
      \draw[thick,->]             (q)++(+1mm,+1mm) -- +(225:4.0mm);}{}
    \ifdefstring{\clcol}{red}{%
      \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (q)++(+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
      \draw[thick,->]             (q)++(+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.0mm);}{}
    }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](-1,-1)grid(2,2);
\pic(n1)[circle] at (0,0){clock=red};
\pic(n2)[right=1cm,anchor=north west] at (n1-c){clock=yellow};
\pic(n3)[above right=1cm and 1cm,anchor=south] at (n1-c){clock=green};
\draw[->](n1-c)edge(n2-c)
         (n2-c)edge(n3-c)
         (n3-c)edge(n1-c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To explain the distance between the black drawn circle and the red circle node in the MWE of the question: the `node contents` is set in a rectangular box and the circle node fits this box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{%
  \node[circle,inner sep=0pt,draw=red,thick]{\tikz{\draw[radius=3.5mm]circle;}};
  \node[draw=blue,thin, dashed,minimum size=7mm]{};
  }
\end{document}
```

---

### 2nd version (without `pic`)

To solve the distance problem in the circle node I use the `minimum size` option instead of `inner sep=0pt`. Using `overlay` for the `node contents` hides its dimension.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    node distance = 5mm,
    start chain = going right,%
    box/.style 2 args = {
      name=n#1,
      draw=#2,
      thick,
      minimum size=7mm+\pgflinewidth,
      on chain,
      node contents={\edef\clcol{#2}\tikz[overlay]{
        \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=\clcol!30] (0,0) circle;
        \fill[radius=3.5mm-0.5*\pgflinewidth,white] (0,0) -- + (90:{3.5mm-0.5*\pgflinewidth}) arc[start angle=90,end angle=135] -- cycle;
        \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
        \ifdefstring{\clcol}{green}{%
          \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
          \draw[thick,->]             ( 0mm,-1mm) -- +( 90:4.0mm);}{}
        \ifdefstring{\clcol}{yellow}{%
          \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
          \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,+1mm) -- +(225:4.0mm);}{}
        \ifdefstring{\clcol}{red}{%
          \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.5mm);
          \draw[thick,->]             (+1mm,-1mm) -- +(135:4.0mm);}{}
        }}
      },
  }
  \node[box={1}{green}];
  \node[box={2}{yellow}];
  \node[box={3}{red},circle];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I understand that `circle` option is applied to inner `-c` node. Could you explain me how?

Comment: It sets the key `/tikz/shape=circle` and therefore `circle` is the default node shape in this `pic`. The same happens for instance in: `\tikz[circle]\node[draw]{};`

Comment: @essed, sorry for late replay, it seem that half of night the page was down ... I liked bot of your answers, but temporary I will stay with secona variant, it is the closed to my (up to now) way of drawing of tikz pictures.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a definitive answer because I don't know how do you want to use this symbols and the code don't use conditioned styles. What I've done was to use `pics` (you need TikZ 3.0).

The first pic `clock` draws the common part of your symbols and the other three pics use it (fixing its filling color) and draw particular characteristics. At the moment, each particular symbol `boxG`, `boxY` and `boxR` fixes its color, so there is no need for a second argument as in your examples.

About the first argument in your example (node name) I was not sure what to do with it and also avoided. If you explain why do you need them, the code could change.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    pics/clock/.style = {
        code = {
            \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#1!30] (0,0) circle;
            \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) 
                arc[start angle=90, end angle=135] -- cycle;
            \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   
                \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
            \draw ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
        }
    },
    pics/boxG/.style = {
        code = {
            \draw[thick,green] (-3.6mm,-3.6mm) rectangle (3.6mm,3.6mm);
            \draw (0,0) pic {clock = {green}};
            \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ ( 90:4.0mm);                              
        }
    },
    pics/boxY/.style = {
        code = {
            \draw[thick,yellow] (-3.6mm,-3.6mm) rectangle (3.6mm,3.6mm);
            \draw (0,0) pic {clock = {yellow}};
            \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] (+1mm,+1mm) -- ++ (225:4.0mm);                              
        }
    },
    pics/boxR/.style= {
        code = {
            \draw[thick,red] (0,0) circle[radius=3.6mm];
            \draw (0,0) pic {clock = {red}};
            \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] ( +1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.0mm);                              
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) pic {boxG};
    \draw (1,0) pic {boxY};
    \draw (2,0) pic {boxR};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version**

Not sure if it's an improvement, but now only one `clock` is defined. Two new keys are added, `border` and `time` with possible values `R`, `G` and `Y`. They select the kind of border and arrow position.

I must admit I don't understand very well how pgfkeys work. It's my first time, so I hope somebody else will correct or propose better answers.

The result is exactly the same than first version, although the syntax has changed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    /border/.is choice,
    /border/G/.code = {
        \draw[thick,green] (-3.6mm,-3.6mm) rectangle (3.6mm,3.6mm);
    },
    /border/Y/.code = { 
        \draw[thick,yellow] (-3.6mm,-3.6mm) rectangle (3.6mm,3.6mm);
    },
    /border/R/.code = { 
        \draw[thick,red] (0,0) circle[radius=3.6mm];
    },
    /time/.is choice,
    /time/G/.code = {
            \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ ( 90:4.0mm);                              
    },
    /time/Y/.code = {
            \draw[orange,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] (+1mm,+1mm) -- ++ (225:4.0mm);                              
    },
    /time/R/.code = {
            \draw[yellow,ultra thick]   (+1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.5mm);
            \draw[thick,->] ( +1mm,-1mm) -- ++ (135:4.0mm);                              
    },
    pics/clock/.style 2 args= {
        code = {
            \pgfkeys{border=#1},    
                \draw[radius=3.5mm,fill=#2!30] (0,0) circle;
                \fill[radius=3.4mm,white] (0,0) -- + (90:3.4mm) 
                arc[start angle=90, end angle=135] -- cycle;
                \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}   
                \draw (0,0) ++ (\i:2.5mm) -- (\i:3mm);
                \draw ( 0mm,-1mm) -- ++ (0mm,4.0mm);
            \pgfkeys{time=#1}
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) pic {clock={G}{green}};
    \draw (1,0) pic {clock={Y}{yellow}};
    \draw (2,0) pic {clock={R}{red}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i thinking about use of pic, but til to now i'm not know how to use it ... names of clocks (timers) I need for placing them. For example yellow one is some distance right/below green one and connected with some, usually with dashed line, so your second version is close to this, for what i looking for. temporary I'm occupied with some other obligation, so more detailed tests i will perform late evening.