# Problem with pic name

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-pic

When I compile the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rect/.style={rectangle},
  sum/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=0.2cm,fill=white,drop shadow={shadow xshift=.3ex,shadow yshift=-.3ex}},
  dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt}, 
  pics/integrator/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    code={
      \node[sum] (-in) {};
      \node[dot,right=1.5*\a of -in.center,"above:#2"] (-out) {};
      \node[rect,below=0.5*\a of $(-in.center)!0.5!(-out.center)$,
        "left:#1"{font=\scriptsize,yshift=-0.25cm}] (-int) {$z^{-1}$};
      \draw (-in.center) -- (-out.center);
      \draw[-latex] (-int.center) -| (-in.center);
      \draw[-latex] (-out.center) |- (-int.center);
    }
  }
]  
  \def\a{1cm}
  \pic (int) {integrator=$x_1(k)$ and $B_{coil}$}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the lualatex compiler I get a strange error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named intcurrent path bounding box is known.
l.29 ...c (int) {integrator=$x_1(k)$ and $B_{coil}$};
```

When I remove the name prefix everything compiles fine.

Edit: I tried the workaround from the linked questions, by adding `.center` to every node, but that gives me the same error message as before. I also tested the passing of the name to the pic and resetting the name prefix inside the draw command. Also the same error persists.

Comment: It's a known bug and reported to the PGF/TikZ bug tracker. You can check the duplicate for a workaround

Comment: I did try your workaround, but the error persists. I'm pretty sure this is another problem, possibly related to the mentioned one

Comment: Don't do this: `\def\a{1cm}` outside the picture!

Comment: @cfr what is the reason for doing this inside the picture environment?

Comment: If you say `\def\a` outside the picture, you will overwrite any existing macro `\a` with no warning. If you want it to be global, use `\newcommand` or, better, `\newlength` and `\setlength`. If you want to set `\a` regardless, do it in the `tikzpicture` so it doesn't affect your entire document. `\def\<single letter>` is very, very likely to be overwriting something LaTeX or TeX has already defined and `\def` does no checking whatsoever. Stuff will just break.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you tried to apply the workaround and which workaround you used? Right now, it is not obvious why this isn't a duplicate. If you can show that the workarounds in the linked question don't work, then it will be clearer why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: You probably need e.g. `1.5*\a{} of` as the `\a` will gobble the following space.

Comment: This does not prevent the error from happening

Comment: Please read my suggestion above about editing your question. How did you apply whichever workaround you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is why:

`pic`
⟶  `sum`
⟶ `drop shadow`
⟶ `general shadow`
⟶ `(current path bounding box.center)`
⟶ `\pgfpointanchor{intcurrent path bounding box}{center}`
⟶ `intcurrent path bounding box` is not a valid name.

See [How to give a name to \pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194362/how-to-give-a-name-to-pic/375558).