# tikz pic: no pgfpointanchor possible inside the pic definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

If I use inside the declaration of a tikz-pic the name of a previously defined coordinate, in `\pgfpointanchor{}`, I get `` Package pgf Error: No shape named `COORD` is known. ``

An example of this behavior can be seen below. Where I define two coordinates A and B and then I want to calculate the angle between this two points. But this fails, because in the pic definition latex doesn't know what the coord A or B are.

If I use the same code inside the tikzpicture, it works as expected.
What can I do, to enable the defined coords also inside the pic-definition?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,fit,calc,matrix,decorations.text,arrows.meta,shadows.blur,shapes.symbols,automata,fpu,intersections}

\tikzset{
Test/.pic = {
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 1);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 0);
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}} 
    \draw[red] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=5mm];
    \draw[green] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=\pgfmathresult, radius=5mm];
}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %original pic, which is not working
    \pic[](test1) at (0, 12mm) {Test};

    %this is the reference, which is working, but should be replaced by the pic
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 1);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 0);
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}} 
    \draw[red] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=5mm];
    \draw[green] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=\pgfmathresult, radius=5mm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit annoying part of the `pic` syntax because all nodes infer a `name prefix` from the pic name here it is for example `test1`.

There are a few things you can do but if you are not going to refer to any node in the `pic`, then scope everything and add `[name prefix ..]` option to the scope which resets the name prefix

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{Test/.pic = {
\begin{scope}[name prefix ..]
    \coordinate (A) at (1, 1);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 0);
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
    \let\myresult\pgfmathresult
    \draw[red,thick] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=5mm];
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (B) arc[start angle=0, end angle=\myresult, radius=5mm];
\end{scope}
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[](test1) at (0, 12mm) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but what can I do, if I want to refer to a node in the pic?

Comment: This is not what is in the doc. This looks like a bug : the example of page 254 (v3.0.1a) that precisely describe the name scoping is not working. Following the documentation `name prefix ..` is supposed to be used to access external nodes from inside (and not the other way).

Comment: @Kpym That's because external nodes also don't have any prefix. Hence the same thing happens

Comment: @percusse This is a bug that I was not aware, but [you were](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194403) ;) Probably the [@cfr's workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370) (putting `name prefix ..` only in the `draw`) is a better solution.

Comment: But `name prefix ..` is not supported in `\pgfpointanchor`. (or is it?) Because the main problem is, that `\pgfpointanchor` doesn't see the coordinates.

Comment: @KpymThat's one of the *a few things you can do* :)