# How to give a name to \pic (part II)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

When I was looking for the solutions of [How to give a name to \pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194362), I discovored that it looks like that the problem is only with the code of `\tikztostart` in the `to` path and not with the `\tikztotarget`.

Here is a MWE that shows this (the commented commands are "corrected" by replacing the starting node with explicit coordinates).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  seagull/.pic={
    % Code for a "seagull". Do you see it?...
    \coordinate (-left wing) at (-3mm,0);
    \coordinate (-head) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (-right wing) at (3mm,0);
    % \draw (-left wing) to [bend left] (0,0);
    \draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (-head);
    % \draw (-head) to [bend left] (-right wing);
    \draw (0,0) to [bend left] (-right wing);
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%\small\sffamily
    \pic (Emma) {seagull};
    \pic (Alexandra) at (0,1) {seagull};
    \draw (Emma-left wing) -- (Alexandra-right wing);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**So my question is:** By looking at the difference between `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget` can we imagine a fix up ?

**Note :** I'm not looking for workaround, because in the originals question we can already find : the use of `name prefix ..`, or the replacement of named by explicit coordinates using `let ...`.

Comment: Well I think this is actually a corollary of the same bug. This also works `\draw (-left wing) -- (0,0);` It is related to how the nodes names are collected.

Comment: @percusse I have no problems with `--`. Only `to` paths with named start coordinate throw errors. Your example  do not present the bug when I test it.

Comment: Yes we should find a different canonical example that fails all the time. It is intriguing indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer but to tell you that I do not think it has to do with `\tikztostart` vs. `\tikztotarget`. Rather, I share the opinions of [@cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370/121799), [@Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375558/121799) and [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194403/121799). In more detail, I think that it is just a coincidence that your code works, it does simply because the parsing starts from `\tikztostart`.

The only very modest improvement to [@cfr's great workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370/121799) is that you do no longer have to type `seagull=`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{ 
  seagull/.pic={
    \coordinate (-left wing) at (-3mm,0);
    \coordinate (-head)      at (0,0);
    \coordinate (-right wing) at (3mm,0);
    \xdef\myname{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/name prefix}}
    \draw[name prefix=]  (\myname-left wing) to [bend left] (\myname-head) to [bend left] (\myname-right wing);
  }
}

\tikz {
  \pic (Emma)               {seagull};
  \pic (Alexandra) at (0,1) {seagull};

  \draw (Emma-left wing) -- (Alexandra-right wing);
}

\end{document}
```

I also think that this should not be necessary. In particular, I copied the preamble from the pgfmanual, i.e. loaded all the libraries, and then just made a document with the example from the bottom of page 254. And it failed. But the pgfmanual does compile, doesn't it?

What is also suspicious is the seemingly superfluous `(0,0)` in

```
\draw (-left wing) to [bend left] (0,0) (-head) to [bend left] (-right wing);
```

in the manual. Why was that added?

Comment: Thanks but I do not agree with your analysis : as you can see in my example the problem arrives with only one named `\tikztostart`. And you can check that with two named `\tikztotarget` there's no problem. And by the way, as I note in my question, I'm not looking for workaround.

Comment: @Kpym I am sorry, I disagree. I think that this is just a coincidence because parsing goes from start to target.

Comment: @Kpym I have restored a modified version of my answer. I understand that you may not like it, but IMHO the fact that you've presented a code that does not fail does not really prove that the issue is due to  `\tikztostart`. There are many possible other explanations for this, and I think that this is simply due to the parsing order. You can check this by replacing your code by `\draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (-head) to [bend left] (-right wing);`. Then for the second leg `(-head) ` is also a `\tikztostart` node/coordinate, but it still works.