# `No shape named` error with a prefixed `pic` and a tree with a child

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

If I try to define a tree, with a child, inside a pic and later use this pic with a prefix, I get an error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset {
      tree/.pic = {
        \coordinate (-root) child;
      }
    }
    \pic[draw] (t) {tree};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named tt-root is known.

It works fine if I delete `child` from the pic or don't try to prefix the `\pic` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194362/121799), do you agree?

Comment: Indeed. It isn't straight forward to see, as my problem starts with a tree, and not the key `to`, but the issue seems to be the same. Thank you for the reference. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I could also close it as a duplicate. Believe me, many top users have tried to solve it, but so far I am only aware of workarounds, some of which are of course very ingenious. Closing this question may be more appropriate since then the original one is easier to find. What do you think?

Comment: I defer to your judgement. Thank you for being great.

Comment: Maybe you can solve the question.... ;-) I am always wondering about one very basic thing: the pgfmanual itself *can* be compiled without errors. So what is going on here? I tried to load all libraries, just like the pgfmanual does, hoping this would fix it, but it doesn't.