# New shapes with fixed dimensions and without text

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the valuable help of [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot), I am designing new shapes with fixed dimensions. If I write text in these nodes, they are not adapted to the text. I need to eliminate the posibility of writing anything, because I don't need it. Does somebody know the way to do it?

Comment: If you do not want to have any text content, you might be better off using `pic`s. True, they do not have anchors with the same syntax as nodes, but they can have anchors in the sense of prefixed coordinates. If you are just bugged by getting rid of the node contents, you can just add `node contents={}` to the style with which you are using the shape.

Comment: @marmot `name prefix` for `pic`s is currently broken: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/312/

Comment: @HenriMenke Why does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194362/121799 work then on my machine? Previously it didn't. I was under the impression it got fixed.

Comment: @marmot It doesn't nest `pic`s.  Nesting is still broken.

Comment: @aguivald Could you please explain your question further? I can't get it.

Comment: @JouleV In brief, I need to avoid writing in my new shapes like they were nodes. Use of node contents={} (suggestion of @marmot) is good for me.

Comment: @marmot I've been taking a look at pic. A the first sight I encounter two questions: 1) It seems that I can't use '.' like anchors; 2) The speed or compilations versus use of anchors. However, I'll try to make the same new shape with pic.