# Draw arrows between nodes defined in a pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

How can I draw an arrow between two nodes that are defined in a `pic` please. 
For example, how can I draw an edge from node A in the left hand side to the node A in the right hand side? Thank you.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={draw, -latex},
mypic/.pic = {  
  \node[draw] (a) {A};
  \node[draw, below of=a] (b) {B};}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {mypic};
  \pic at (1,1) {mypic}; 
  \draw[arrow] (a.north east)--(a.south west); % unsurprisingly this doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat; no, I'd like to draw an edge between the nodes from the different pics. i.e from A to A, and B to B. Perhaps I should add  label parameters to the pics?

Comment: Oh, sorry!  OK. I see. Tried to answer this below.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the node `a`. You need to give it unique names, e.g. with.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={draw, -latex},
mypic/.pic = {  
  \node[draw] (#1-a) {A};
  \node[draw, below of=#1-a] (#1-b) {B};}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) pic {mypic=L};
  \path (1,1) pic {mypic=R}; 
  \draw[arrow] (L-a.north east)--(R-a.south west); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In principle you could also use the names of the pics, see the example on top of p. 263 of the pgf manual. However, in practice [difficulties arise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194362), so I decided to go the way above.